# Get users from two tables where id's are not the same

Tags: sql, laravel

I ran across on a pretty though query for Rest API. Want to hear your recommendations.

Now I have two tables :

1. **Company Users**: which stores major information about the registered users like:
   **id, name, email, phone number.**
2. **Matching_users**: which stores the information like: 
   **active_user_id, matching_user_id** where active user id is the authorized user ID, and matching user id is the any other user id which Authorized user have met before.

The question is: how I could execute the query where I would be able to fetch all other users (except authorized user ID, and users with whom authorized user would have met before )?

For example:

TABLE : **company_users**

---

ID | NAME | EMAIL

---

1  | Jake | jake@gmail.com

---

2 | Jane | jane@gmail.com

---

3 | Jacob | jacob@gmail.com

---

4 | June | june@gmail.com

and

TABLE : **matching_table**

ID | ACTIVE_USER_ID | MATCHING_USER_ID

---

1 | 1 | 2

How can I execute for authorized user only users from **company_userswith** id 3 and 4?

Answer (score 0):

Get all rows of table 2 :

```
$matching_rows = MatchingTable::all();
$active_users = $matching_rows->pluck('active_user_id')->toArray();
$matching_users = $matching_rows->pluck('active_user_id')->toArray();
```

Merging them together :

```
$auth_users = array_merge($active_users, $matching_users);
```

Using whereNotIn :

```
$unauth_users = Users::whereNotIn('id', $auth_users)->get()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

If Except ACTIVE_USER_ID Then

```
Select * from company_users
Where Id NOT IN ( SELECT Distinct ACTIVE_USER_ID  FROM matching_table)
```

If Except MATCHING_USER_ID Then

```
Select * from company_users
Where Id NOT IN ( SELECT Distinct MATCHING_USER_ID FROM matching_table)
```

If Except ACTIVE_USER_ID and MATCHING_USER_ID Then

```
Select * from company_users
Where Id NOT IN ( SELECT Distinct MATCHING_USER_ID  FROM matching_table)
AND Id NOT IN ( SELECT Distinct ACTIVE_USER_ID  FROM matching_table)
```